# maven cannot find symbol

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I am running a clean test on my maven project.  I am getting the following error:

```
[ERROR] /Users/afrieden/Projects/CLO-processing/src/main/java/com/aws/mongodb/AWSMongoLoader.java:[51,9] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   variable MongoUtility
[ERROR] location: class com.aws.mongodb.AWSMongoLoader
```

I got this part from running mvn clean test.  These two classes are in the same namespace.  `MongoUtility` is a class that just has a bunch of static methods I am using to load data.

Versions of everything:

```
Apache Maven 3.2.3 (33f8c3e1027c3ddde99d3cdebad2656a31e8fdf4; 2014-08-11T16:58:10-04:00)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.2.3/libexec
Java version: 1.7.0_17, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.9.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Associated POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>CLO-processing</groupId>
<artifactId>CLO-processing</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>qa</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>install</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!--<plugin>-->
                    <!--<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>-->
                    <!--<version>2.1</version>-->
                <!--</plugin>-->
                <!--<plugin>-->
                    <!--<artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>-->
                    <!--<version>1.8.1</version>-->
                    <!--<configuration>-->
                        <!--<tag>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</tag>-->
                    <!--</configuration>-->
                <!--</plugin>-->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.9</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <useFile>false</useFile>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>in-project</id>
        <name>In Project Repo</name>
        <url>file://${project.basedir}/libs</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mygroupid</groupId>
        <artifactId>mycustomartifact</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder</groupId>
        <artifactId>http-builder</artifactId>
        <version>0.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.utgenome.thirdparty</groupId>
        <artifactId>picard</artifactId>
        <version>1.86.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
        <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

What is going wrong here?  I am able to do `mvn test` fine with the intellij compiled class files.  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

something is wrong with your java file.
the path is: com/aws/mongodb/AWSMongoLoader
but the error talks about location: class com.gsg.aws.mongodb.AWSMongoLoader
which means the package declaration got gsg there, but its not the right path in the file system.

Comment: Sorry removed that for simplicity and to keep as much IP stuff off of here as possible.  Still same error.  I have fixed this in the question